Convert a Graph to a Good Graph using Maximum Mathcing in Bipartite Graphs Algorithm
Consider a graph G=(V,E) where a vertex v∈V is designated as the center if it is connected to every other vertex u∈V, such that both uv and vu are present in E. A graph is deemed 'good' if it has a single center, and all other vertices have equal in-degrees and out-degrees of 2.
Given a directed graph G=(V,E), my objective is to transform it into a 'good' graph by making the fewest possible modifications. Each modification can either be the deletion or addition of a directed edge. If the time complexity to find a maximum matching in a bipartite graph is T(n), I aim to devise an algorithm with a time complexity of O(nT(n)) that determines the minimum number of changes needed to convert G into a 'good' graph.
I think I kinda should connect minimum modifications needed to maximum mathcing somehow and use it n times. But I'm really stuck on finding such a realtion. I would be extremely grateful for any assistance with this problem.

Can you add inputs and expected outputs to your question?

@user24714692 As you can see, a graph is given and the output is the minimum number of modifications needed to convert the input graph to a good graph, which is defined in the question body.

Always use spellcheck!!!
